# Java SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match for www.googleapis.com

Tags: java, ssl, google-api, google-custom-search

**Environment**: Mac OS X Lion & Linux Debian squeeze/sid, JDK 1.7.0 & JDK 1.6.0_27

**Error**:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <www.googleapis.com/74.125.47.95> != <*.googleapis.com> OR <googleapis.com> OR <*.googleapis.com> .
```

I'm getting this error in all the above OS/JDK combinations.

**Background**: I am using google-api-services-customsearch and google-api-service-shopping jars to do webservice calls to Google. My calls were working correctly until a day ago. Since yesterday, the code has started to throw...

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <www.googleapis.com/74.125.47.95> != <*.googleapis.com> OR <googleapis.com> OR <*.googleapis.com>
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:228)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier.verify(BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier.java:54)
.....
    at com.google.api.services.shopping.Shopping$Products$List.execute(Shopping.java:156)
```

I tried importing the cert into the `cacerts` keystore using [the instructions here](http://www.chrissearle.org/node/260), but that does not seem to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient(true,80,443);
```